# AppleScript to control BlackMagic Videohubs

Tags: applescript, blackmagic-design

EDIT: The goal is for it to fire commands like:

```
VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:
0 1
2 1
3 1
6 1
7 1
8 1
9 1
10 1
11 1
↩
```

Although the issue is that it terminates before attempting to fire a command, due to the port being incorrect.

I am working on the following AppleScript to control Blackmagic Design Videohub routers, via netcat, and I am having some trouble. I can't seem to pass the port correctly to netcat. My current error is *nc: port range not valid*. I removed device names and IPs for the purpose of this post. Any ideas?

```
display dialog "Choose an option:" buttons {"Live", "Cut to Channel"}
set userChoice to button returned of result

on sendCommand(IP, port, command)
   do shell script "printf " & quoted form of command & " | nc " & IP & " " & (port as string)
end sendCommand

on checkACK(reply)
   if reply contains "NAK" then
      display dialog "Error: " & reply
   end if
end checkACK

if userChoice is "Live" then
   --Clean Switch commands
   set CleanSwitchIP to "[IP]"
   set CleanSwitchPort to "[Port]"
   set commands to "VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:\\n0 1\\n2 1\\n3 1\\n6 1\\n7 1\\n8 1\\n9 1\\n10 1\\n11 1\\n"
   
   set reply to sendCommand(CleanSwitchIP, CleanSwitchPort, commands)
   checkACK(reply)
   
   -- Video Hub commands
   set VideoHubIP to "[IP]"
   set VideoHubPort to "[PORT]"
   set command to "VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:\\n24 12\\n"
   
   set reply to sendCommand(VideoHubIP, VideoHubPort, command)
   checkACK(reply)
   
   -- Video Hub 2 commands
   set VideoHub2IP to "[IP]"
   set VideoHub2Port to "[PORT]"
   set commands to "VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:\\n13 30\\n14 30\\n15 30\\n16 30\\n20 30\\n22 30\\n23 30\\n24 30\\n25 30\\n27 30\\n"
   
   set reply to sendCommand(VideoHub2IP, VideoHub2Port, commands)
   checkACK(reply)
   
   display dialog "You are now Live to the studio!"
   
else if userChoice is "Cut to Channel" then
   -- Clean Switch commands
   set CleanSwitchIP to "[IP]"
   set CleanSwitchPort to "[Port]"
   set commands to "VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:\\n0 0\\n2 0\\n3 0\\n6 0\\n7 0\\n8 0\\n9 0\\n10 0\\n11 0\\n"
   
   set reply to sendCommand(CleanSwitchIP, CleanSwitchPort, commands)
   checkACK(reply)
   
   -- Video Hub 2 commands
   set VideoHub2IP to "[IP]"
   set VideoHub2Port to "[Port]"
   set commands to "VIDEO OUTPUT ROUTING:\\n13 30\\n14 30\\n15 30\\n16 30\\n20 30\\n22 30\\n23 30\\n24 30\\n25 30\\n27 30\\n"
   
   set reply to sendCommand(VideoHub2IP, VideoHub2Port, commands)
   checkACK(reply)
   
end if
```

I've tried several different ways of declaring the port, but without any luck.

Comment: Maybe click [edit] and include the plain command that works in your normal Terminal. Then print the command from your Applescript before you send it. Then add the error messages and problems.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. How can you send the full, actual, working command in Terminal? Also, what port are you using in the script?

Comment: It has to initiate a connection, and wait for the prelude to be done.  The Videohub will rattle off the current state of the device.  Then you make a command, such as the one above.  Unfortunately I don't think it can all be done in one command.  Port 9990

Comment: There's a document here that tells you how to do it... https://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/DeveloperManuals/VideohubDeveloperInformation.pdf It also says you need 2 CR at the end, btw.

Comment: Example here also has extra blank line at end https://codepen.io/thisisnotgroiss/pen/RwoMrGY?editors=1010